# How do you list all files without a suffix using Perl?

Tags: perl, file-io

I want to add a suffix to all the files without a suffix in a directory with mixed content.

1. I only want to fetch files without a suffix
2. Then I want to add a suffix to them (like, say, `.txt` or `.html`)

It's part one I'm having trouble with.

I'm using `glob` to fetch all the files. Here's the code excerpt:

```
 my @files = grep ( -f, <*> );
```

`-f` makes sure only files are added, and the `*` wildcard allows all names.

But how do I rewrite that to only fetch files that have no suffix? Or in the least, how do I wash the array of suffixed files?

Comment: Your current use of grep seems rather incorrect to me. Is it working?

Comment: The code that you have posted, `my @files = grep ( -f <*> );`, throws a syntax error.  You couldn't possibly be using that code.  It is always best to cut & paste your code rather than retyping it.

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot a comma. :) It should of course be `my @files = grep ( -f ,<*>);`

Comment: What do you consider to be a suffixed file? It is simple to find names that don't contain a dot, but what about anything ending or beginning with a dot?

Comment: I think you have asked the wrong question. What is the overall problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: What is the suffix of `script.file`?  What is the suffix of `raw.data`?

Comment: Or indeed `file.with.punctiation.instead.of.whitespace`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file without a suffix is one without a dot in its name.

```
my @files = grep { -f and not /\./ } <*>;
```

Comment: For the sake of argument, let us say the files also have random punctuations (they may, when you download files with Wget, for instance). Then what?

Comment: Then you must define more precisely what it is that you want to include, perhaps including the contents of the file? If you are using `wget` then you can filter using the MIME type of the resource.

Comment: Nice, thank you! :) I accept this one because it's the simplest to understand, and it seems the easiest to expand upon.

Comment: -1 This will not work with a multitude of file names, such as those mentioned in the comments. Simply checking for a period is a simplistic solution at best.

Comment: @TLP: Without a better specification for what a *file with a suffix* means exactly it is wrong to speculate. Your comment on your own question says that you *left the regex vague* for exactly this reason, but you were clearly not vague *enough*.

Comment: @Borodin Well, clearly the question cannot reasonably be answered with the information given. However, going as vague as possible is not the answer, then you will only get a lot of false positives.

Answer (score 2):

You can just tack on another grep statement:

```
my @files = grep !/\.\w{1,4}$/, grep -f, <*>;
#           -------------------
```

Or you can, as Borodin points out, do it in one:

```
my @files = grep !/\.\w{1,4}$/ && -f, <*>;
```

You can change the regex to fit better depending on what type of suffixes you have. The regex looks for files which do not match a period, followed by 1 to 4 alphanumeric characters, at the end of the string. I opted for a rather loose regex to match a multitude of possible suffixes.

Comment: Cool, what is actually going on in those regular expressions?

Comment: @Kebman: The code checks for a *file* that doesn't have a dot followed by one to four *word* characters (alphanumeric or `_`). It does it unnecessarily in two stages, and is the same as `grep !/\.\w{1,4}$/ && -f, <*>`

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. It taught me a lot! However, this answer would still catch files with suffixes like for instance .torrent, wouldn't it?

Comment: If by "catch" you mean "match", then yes. `.torrent` does not have 1 to 4 characters after the period. If you want to match such long extensions, you could use `{1,7}` or even `+` as quantifier. But then it will match even such files as `some.foobar`. This is the reason I left the regex vague, because only you know what kind of extensions to expect.

Comment: Hm, so if you had files with, say, punctuation rather than whitespace, you'd have to find another solution?

Comment: Well, it certainly would not work to just look for a period in the file name. If you want it to be flawless, you have to be able to predict what kind of file names you will have. If they are basically random, you're out of luck. Then you might be better off creating a list of known extensions and look for those. E.g. make a regex such as `!/\.(txt|html|torrent|etc)$/`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`, all you need is to add a regular expression:

```
my @files = grep { !/\.\w+\z/ && -f } ( <*> );
```